# How to handle non-model data in ember

Tags: ember.js, tabular

I want to retrieve tabular data related to a model and display it in a table.
I am not sure how to do that in ember. Here is what I tried :

I added a get action on my API that return a json with the data

`model_path\:id\related_data`

I added a custom action to the model :

`allShares: modelAction('all_shares',{type: 'GET'})`

ANd here is how I add it to the route's model :

`allShares: invoice.then((i)=>{return i.allShares()})`

Now I have a `model.allShares` that should contain the data. In the network inspector I can see that there has been a query to the endpoint returning the JSON data I want to display.

The following code in the view is totally blank :

```hbs
{{#each model.allShares as |elem index|}}
  {{elem}}
  {{index}}
{{/each}}
```

I can now see a big object in the inspector (using debugger in model()) and I am not sure what to do of it, or even what type of object is it.

What can I do now to display the data in my view ?

EDIT :

{{log model.allShares}} <s>is blank</s>
Ok, I did not knew log was for the console.
It display the object with the data from the JSON.I should now find how to use the data in the view.

{{model.allShares}} return `[object Object]`

Comment: what is `modelAction`? Honestly I would just manually `fetch` the stuff in the route. What happens if you do `{{log model.allShares}}` in the template or just `{{model.allShares}}`?

Comment: WHere can I find info on fetch in Ember?

Comment: what's the value of `model` when you `{{log model}}`?

Comment: It's also blank. It's strange because I display data from the model on the page.

Comment: Ok so log use the terminal, did not knew that.

Comment: `log model` is blank, but you're displaying model data? that doesn't seem right. `{{log model}}` should show everything in the console so that you can further debug, and check your logic vs what the data actually is.

Comment: You can use [ember-fetch](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-fetch) however the fetch API itself is not part of ember but standard JS.

Comment: What is preventing this from being an ember model? If this is related data you can include a "Links" object with the original model that references the path to the relationship. Ember data will then call that route when trying to access the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Based off the question it appears you are trying to load a relationship for a model. A very simple way to this is by including that relationship in the model it self.

Model Blog JSON:

```
{ 
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foo",
    "links": {
        "authors": "/api/blogs/1/authors"
    }
}
```

Ember Model Blog:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    authors: DS.hasMany('author'),
});
```

This is an example of a blog model with a "hasMany" relationship to authors. When this is loaded into ember data, ember will now use that route instead of trying to call the relationship one by one or with an "ids" request (depending on your serializer config)

This will also be called when trying to be used in a template.

I usually find this to be better than using custom methods on models. I only resort to that when I absolutely have too. It's better to work with Ember data rather than against it.

Resources:

- https://thejsguy.com/2016/02/21/handling-nested-resources-in-ember-data.html

Comment: This is the correct answer, especially where you have control over your API responses.

If you ever do not, look into using something like ember-ajax or ember-fetch services to request specific data. This should only be used when ABSOLUTELY NECESSARY though, and you should do everyhting you can to keep critical data in the model ecosystem.